# How to get image url from a string in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have found this:

```
var reg_exUrl = "/(http|https)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
```

however, there is no defined ending, and i would like the found link to have the ending in: .png OR .jpg OR .gif

I believe i need to add something like `(.png|.jpg|.gif)` at the end, but i dont know the specific format. Help.

Comment: `[a-zA-Z]{2,3}` is looking for two or three letter characters at the end \- so replace that with `(png|jpg|gif)` (the dot is already matched before.)

Comment: Allright, awsome. Thank you for the help. I also keep the      (\/\S*)?/      at the end right?

Comment: Try [`/https?:\/\/[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?(?:png|jpg|gif)$/i`](https://regex101.com/r/lK2hD4/1) - is that you are looking for?